# How to join two array for csv-like new array by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

I want to join js array for csv like.
So, how to simply(no use "for" if I can) write code please tell me.
Only use Chrome.

```
let arr1 = ["hoge","piyo", "fuga"];
let arr2 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
//Want to array
let arrResult = ["hoge,foo","piyo,bar", "fuga,baz"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get there.

```js
let arr1 = ["hoge", "piyo", "fuga"];
let arr2 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
let combo = arr1.map((el, i) => [el, arr2[i]].join(","))
console.log(combo)
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```js
let arr1 = ["hoge", "piyo", "fuga"];
let arr2 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
let arrResult = [];

for(let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  arrResult[i] = `${arr1[i]},${arr2[i]}`;
}

console.log(arrResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let arr1 = ["hoge", "piyo", "fuga"];
let arr2 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
let arrResult = [];
arr1.forEach((item,index) => {
  if(index < arr2.length){
     arrResult[index] = `${item},${arr2[index]}`;
  }
})
```